# Открытие разных DialogFragment с условием входа пользователя

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

При нажатии на `CardView` открывается `DialogFragment1` с авторизацией пользователя, после того как он авторизовался этот `DialogFragment1` закрывается и мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на этот же `CardView` открывался `DialogFragment2`, то есть нужно сделать условия что при авторизированном пользователе открывался другой `DialogFragment`. Как это сделать?

Это `CardView` по нажатию на который открывается `DialogFragment` с авторизацией

```
profile.setOnClickListener(v -> {
         DialogProfile dialog = new DialogProfile();
         dialog.show(requireFragmentManager(), "DialogProfile");
     });
```

Так выглядит метод с помощью которого проходит авторизация

```
    private void performSignUp() {
        String userName = User_Name_Reg.getText().toString();
        String userSurname = User_Surname_Reg.getText().toString();
        String userEmail = User_Email_Reg.getText().toString();
        String userPassword = User_Password_Reg.getText().toString();
        String userRepassword = User_Repassword_Reg.getText().toString();

        Call<ApiResponse> call = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class).performUserSignIn(userName, userSurname, userEmail, userPassword, userRepassword);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse> call, Response<ApiResponse> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    if (response.body().getStatus().equals("ok")) {
                        if (response.body().getResultCode() == 1) {
                            FragmentDialogLogin.displayUserInformation(getString(R.string.Registration_completed));
                            int current = DialogAuthorization.VP_dialog_authorization.getCurrentItem();
                            if (current != 0) {
                                DialogAuthorization.VP_dialog_authorization.setCurrentItem(current - 1, true);
                            }
                        } else {
                            displayUserInfo(getString(R.string.User_already_exists));
                            User_Password_Reg.setText("");
                        }
                    } else {
                        displayUserInfo(getString(R.string.Something_went_wrong));
                        User_Password_Reg.setText("");
                    }

                } else {
                    displayUserInfo(getString(R.string.Something_went_wrong));
                    User_Password_Reg.setText("");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть это всё находится в `Activity`. Изменяете `boolean isAuthorized` на `true` в случае успешной регистрации и проверяете при нажатии:

```
boolean isAuthorized = false;

//Регистрация
private void performSignUp() {
    /*
    Your code here...
    */
                        FragmentDialogLogin.displayUserInformation(getString(R.string.Registration_completed));
                        isAuthorized = true;
    /*
    Your code here...
    */
}

//Нажатие на CardView
profile.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    if (isAuthorized) {
        DialogProfileAuthorized dialog = new DialogProfileAuthorized();
        dialog.show(requireFragmentManager(), "DialogProfileAuthorized");
    } else {
        DialogProfile dialog = new DialogProfile();
        dialog.show(requireFragmentManager(), "DialogProfile");
    }
});
```